Purge attachment only works with destroy and not destroy_all method when triggers callback
I'm having trouble purging images stored in an S3 bucket after destroying a record with attachments. I searched i lont but i can't figure out what's causing this issue.
I have a Tour model with two types of attachments: a cover_image (single) and images (multiple).
The creation process works well. I'm using Rails as an API, sending a POST request with form data. In my controller, I'm attaching the images like this:
def create_tour
      if(@params[:tour_cover_image].present?)
        tour_images = @params.select{ |key, _| key.to_s.start_with?('tour_image-') }
        tour = Tour.new(@tour_params)
        tour.save!
        tour.cover_image.attach(
          io: File.open(@params[:tour_cover_image].tempfile),
          filename: @params[:tour_cover_image].original_filename,
          content_type: @params[:tour_cover_image].content_type,
          key: "public/tours/#{tour.id}/cover_image/#{SecureRandom.uuid}-#{@params[:tour_cover_image].original_filename}"
        )
        tour_images.each do |key, image|
          tour.images.attach(
            io: File.open(image.tempfile),
            filename: image.original_filename,
            content_type: image.content_type,
            key: "public/tours/#{tour.id}/images/#{SecureRandom.uuid}-#{image.original_filename}"
          )
        end
      else
        tour = Tour.new(@tour_params.except(:images, :cover_image))
        tour.save!
      end
      tour
    end

I also created a Rake task to clean up my development database by destroying all records:
namespace :tours do
  desc "This will destroy all tours and their dependencies"
  task destroy_all: :environment do
    Tour.destroy_all
    puts "All tours and their dependencies have been destroyed"
  end
end

In my Tour model, I added a callback to purge all images from S3 when a record is destroyed:
class Tour < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :tour_vehicles_tours, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tour_vehicles, through: :tour_vehicles_tours
  has_many :schedule_stop, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :user
  has_one_attached :cover_image
  has_many_attached :images

  before_destroy :purge_images

  def purge_images
    images.purge
    cover_image.purge
  end
end

Here's the problem:

When I run Tour.destroy_all via the Rake task, the purge_images callback is triggered, but only the cover_image is removed from S3. The images are not purged, and images.attached? returns false in the callback.

However, when I destroy a record manually using Tour.last.destroy, the callback works as expected, and both the cover_image and images are purged from S3.


What could be causing this inconsistency between destroy_all and destroy?
EDIT
So, i face that problem for some days and i find a solution, i don't know if is the best, but it solves for now.
Below is the code for purging the images after destroy an record.
class Tour < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :cover_image
  has_many_attached :images # I tried the dependent: :purge here, but not works

  after_destroy_commit :purge_images

  def purge_images
    begin
      if cover_image.attached?
        cover_image.purge
        Rails.logger.info "Successfully purged cover image for Tour #{id}"
      end
      images = ActiveStorage::Blob.where("key LIKE ?", "public/tours/#{id}/images/%")
      if images.size > 0
        images.each(&:purge)
        Rails.logger.info "Successfully purged #{images.size} images for Tour #{id}"
      end
    rescue StandardError => e
      Rails.logger.error "Failed to purge images for Tour #{id}: #{e.message}"
    end
  end


The default for has_many_attached, and  has_one_attached is to :purge_later.  I suspect that when you call destroy_all this is queueing up lots of objects to destroy in the background.  This happens before your callback. That's why you get images.attached? == false. Try changing  has_many_attached :images to  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :purge and has_one_attached :cover_image to has_one_attached :cover_image, dependent: :purge and get rid of the callback and it should behave as you expect.  But I'd be tempted to get rid of the callback and leave things as they are.

Thank you for the answer, i have tried that dependent: purge and also dependent: purge_later but actually the behavior continues the same, only destroying with destroy make the purge works.
And you also said that default is purge_later, but i can't find about it on the docs of Active Storage, can you show me where can i check this ?

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v7.2/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/Model.html#method-i-has_many_attached

Do you have background jobs configured in you environment?

@spickermann yes, i have a sidekiq running jobs on the background, i have already accessed the dashboard and check and there isn't any jobs of purge or anything there

edited: I think this answer might be more intuitive than the callback
class Tour < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :cover_image, dependent: :destroy
  has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy
end

Hi from docs https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/destroy_all it should work as expected. can you try adding this and see what it logs?
  def purge_images
    # Add error handling and logging
    begin
      if cover_image.attached?
        cover_image.purge
        Rails.logger.info "Successfully purged cover image for Tour #{id}"
      end

      if images.attached?
        images.purge
        Rails.logger.info "Successfully purged #{images.count} images for Tour #{id}"
      end
    rescue StandardError => e
      Rails.logger.error "Failed to purge images for Tour #{id}: #{e.message}"
      # Optionally re-raise the error if you want to halt the process
      # raise e
    end
  end

another thing is that you want the after_destroy callback instead of the before_destroy
after_destroy_commit :purge_images

you can find the full list of callbacks here https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html#destroy-callbacks

Hey, thank you for the answer, so i tried that, i change the callback and put some logs there, now, when i run destroy_all , the callback is deleting only the cover_image (has_one_attached), but the images (has_many) still there, i debug and check, the images.attached? returns false.

class Tour < ApplicationRecord   has_one_attached :cover_image, dependent: :destroy   has_many_attached :images, dependent: :destroy 
another thing I'm thinking of is you might be missing dependent: :destroy on the relationship

I tried with dependent: :purge and dependent: :destroy, any of them works unfortunaley
